# Humanize em caracteres com acento

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gem

Estou com o seguinte problema, tenho algumas mensagens de erro no meu sistema, porém quando há a ocorrência de acentos nas mensagens, o humanize não se aplica a esses caracteres, tentei utilizar a `gem 'brazilian-rails'`, porém como ela está descontinuada, acabou acontecendo alguns bugs em meu sistema.

Exemplo do meu erro:

```
"Número É muito longo (máximo: 9 caracteres)"
```

Mesmo com o humanize, o é continua em maiúsculo.

Utilizo Rails 3.2.15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode dar um exemplo de como está usando o humanize?

Em todo caso, é um problema com o UTF-8.

Faça o teste no console

```
"É".downcase
```

Não funciona, enquanto

```
"É".mb_chars.downcase
```

sim.

Então uma saída seria utilizar:

```
"Número É muito longo (máximo: 9 caracteres)".mb_chars.downcase.humanize
```

Comment: Realmente funcionou, muito obrigado!